# How do I solve $(\cos2x+1)^2=1/2$?

Tags: trigonometry

$x$ belongs to $$[0,\pi/2[$$
$$(\cos(2x+1))^2 = \frac{1}{2}$$

I tried to find $x$ using
$$2x+1=\frac{\pi}{4} +\frac{n\pi}{2}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
2x+1=\frac{3\pi}{4}  + n\pi$$
but I didn't find my answer in MCQ which is
$$\frac{3\pi-4}{8}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{5\pi-4}{8}.$$
I just need a hint on how to solve such equation.

Comment: What is "MCQ"? ${}$

Comment: Multiple choice question

Comment: @Hasan, use only first condition and form constraint for $n$ given that $x\in[0,π/2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inital step is right, indeed we have that

$$(\cos(2x+1))^2 =\frac12 \iff \cos(2x+1)=\pm\frac{\sqrt 2}2 \iff 2x+1=\frac \pi 4+k\frac \pi 2$$

then

$$x=\frac \pi 8+k\frac \pi 4-\frac12$$

and since $x\in [0,\pi/2[$ we obtain

$$x_1=\frac 3 8\pi-\frac12, x_2=\frac 5 8\pi-\frac12$$

Comment: but how did you find k
i got 0.12<x<2.1 so the value of k=1 !

Comment: f@Hasan We have that or $k=0 \implies x<0$ and for $k=3 \implies x>\pi/2$ therefore $k=1,2$ are the correct values. See also [HERE](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B-1%2F2+%2B+%CF%80%2F8%2C+-1%2F2+%2B+%283+%CF%80%29%2F8%2C+-1%2F2+%2B+%285+%CF%80%29%2F8%2C+-1%2F2+%2B+%287+%CF%80%29%2F8%2C+-1%2F2+%2B+%289+%CF%80%29%2F8%7D&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D).

Comment: oh my bad , what if i use 3pi/4 +npi would i get same result ?

Comment: @Hasan I don't think so, it is uncorrect.All the solutions to the initial problem are in the form $2x+1=\frac \pi 4+k\frac \pi 2$. I think you would obtain only the first one by $k=0$, but in general it is a wrong solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\implies\cos2(2x+1)=2\cos^2(2x+1)-1=0$$

$2(2x+1)= \dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}2 $ where $n$ is any integer

Now $1\le2x+1\le1+\pi$

If $1\le\dfrac{(2n+1)\pi}4\le1+\pi\iff\dfrac4\pi-2\le n\le\dfrac4\pi\implies n=0,1$

Answer (score 0):

$$
2x+1=\frac{3\pi}{4}  + n\pi
$$
subtract $1$
$$
2x=\frac{3\pi}{4} - 1  + n\pi
$$
Multiply by $1/2$
$$
x=\frac{3\pi}{8} - \frac{1}{2}  + n\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
The two answers shown correspond to $n=0$ and $n=1$.